# C++ regex Visual Studio Community 2015 <regex> gives unexpected results

Tags: c++, regex

Using Visual Studio Community 2015 C++
Unexpected results using

Source code:

```
#include <regex>
int main()
{
    std::regex re("^(.)=(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{1,2})*$");
    std::cmatch cm;
    std::regex_match("f=12/64", cm, re);
    for (unsigned idxMatch = 0; idxMatch < cm.size(); idxMatch++)
    {
        printf("Found Match %d '%s'\n", idxMatch, cm[idxMatch]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

Found Match 0 'f=12/64'
Found Match 1 'f=12/64'
Found Match 2 '12/64'
Found Match 3 '4'

Expected results:

Found Match 0 'f=12/64'
Found Match 1 'f'
Found Match 2 '12'
Found Match 3 '64'

Commentary:

The regex works correctly on multiple other regex systems
including C, Perl, Java, and Javascript.

The regex works correctly on every multiple online tester that I
attempted.

I have tried escaping the "/" with unexpectedly identical results.

I found no clues to possible incorrect regex at the Microsoft website.

Comment: **Stop using printf**.  Use `cout`.  [This shows why using printf() is unsafe](http://rextester.com/FJJYT56856).  Using `cout` the issue cannot be duplicated, while using `printf` those format specifiers are not correct.

Comment: Just tested in VS 2015 Professional, it works OK if I use `cout`, I get 4 groups displayed, `f=12/6`, `f`, `12`, `64`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using `printf` with wrong format specifiers.  The `cm[idxMatch]` is not a null-terminated string, thus the `%s` specifier will not work.  The behavior is undefined when you provide the wrong data type to match the output specifier.

The easiest solution is to use `std::cout`, and typesafe output streams in general.

[Live Example Using Visual Studio 2015 and std::cout](http://rextester.com/FJJYT56856)

To round things out, here is your example using `printf`.  Note the weirdness that is outputted:

[Here is printf weirdness and Visual Studio 2015](http://rextester.com/NKUPR51002)

---

Edit: For g++, there is a runtime error when using `printf`.

[g++ printf runtime error](http://rextester.com/BUH81778)

while using `std::cout`, we get the desired output:

[g++ using std::cout](http://rextester.com/PQVN6423)

Comment: Thank you - I changed the specifier to  cm[idxMatch].str().c_str() and the results where as I expected. Sadly, cout was not an option. Thanks again