# C++ regex with optional groups not working as expected

Tags: regex, option-type

I am using:

```
^-(.)=((\d{1,3})(F|f))*((\d{1,2})(I|i))*((\d{1,2})(/(2|4|8|16|32|64))*)*$
```

against

```
-s=35
```

The pattern match results is

```
Found Match 0 '-s=35'
Found Match 1 's'
Found Match 2 ''
Found Match 3 ''
Found Match 4 ''
Found Match 5 ''
Found Match 6 ''
Found Match 7 ''
Found Match 8 '5'
Found Match 9 '5'
Found Match 10 ''
Found Match 11 ''
```

I expected it to pick up 35
in sub-group

```
((\d{1,2})(/(2|4|8|16|32|64))*
```

specifically the regex sub-group

```
(\d{1,2})
```

but the leading digit '3' has been lost.
The previous optional sub-groups should not be used because both require a trailing case insensitive letter.
The data `-s=7` works as expected.

Comment: Are you sure? It works fine on [regex storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e-%28.%29%3d%28%28%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%29%28F%7cf%29%29*%28%28%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%29%28I%7ci%29%29*%28%28%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%29%28%2f%282%7c4%7c8%7c16%7c32%7c64%29%29*%29*%24&i=-s%3d35) but that is a .NET tester.

Comment: Is it your [`printf` issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237286/c-regex-visual-studio-community-2015-regex-gives-unexpected-results) again?

Comment: Works fine also with [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/IY37dM/1)

Comment: It *is* matched with that group, it is Group 8.

Comment: what is your input? what do you need to find in string with your pattern?

Comment: @smkplus the question is pretty explicit IMHO

Comment: Probably, your c++ library that use using regex lib is corrupted. How do I know? Because your regex is surrounded by anchors `^$` and groups 8 and 9 cannot contain anything but  `35`/

Comment: Not a printf problem because this is the statement used was                                              printf("Found Match %d '%s'\n", idxMatch, cm[idxMatch].str().c_str());

Comment: Wiktor, thank you for your reply, however, group 8 is not a correct value. For some reason the '35' pattern was not picked up.  However, the 2nd digit in any 2 digit example is only picked up.

Comment: I am using Microsoft C++ in Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: Test program code that produced the result is as follows:

Comment: Test code part 1:#include <regex>
#include <time.h>
#define ARGV_PROGRAM_NAME  0
#define ARGV_REGEX    1
#define ARGV_DATA    2
#define ARGV_LAST_ARG   2
#define ARGV_COUNT    3
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
 if (argc != ARGV_COUNT)
 {
  printf("ERR - Incorrect Argument Count, Expected %d, Found %d\n",
   ARGV_LAST_ARG, argc - 1);
  printf("TestCPPRegex <Regex Pattern> <Data String>\n");
  return -1;
 }

Comment: Test code part 2: std::regex re(argv[ARGV_REGEX]);
 std::cmatch cm;
 std::regex_match(argv[ARGV_DATA], cm, re);
 if (cm.size() == 0)
 {
  printf("No Matches Found\n");
 }
 else
 {
  for (unsigned idxMatch = 0; idxMatch < cm.size(); idxMatch++)
  {
   printf("Found Match %d '%s'\n", idxMatch, cm[idxMatch].str().c_str());
  }
 }
 return 0;
}

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - I agree with you findings.  Sadly, the C++ Regex Library from Microsoft does not get the same results.  Not all the Regex Libraries adhere to the ANSI standard.  I have found other regex expressions that have slightly different syntax based on the underlying library.  I was hoping that there was some misunderstanding on my part for the expression. - Depressing

Comment: @Thomas Ayoub - see my comment to TheLethalCoder above - thanks to both of you for your efforts. - I guess I need to write a small state recognizer for the expression. - exactly what regex provides - LOL

Answer (score 1):

@ sln

Thank you for your efforts.
I am running a (very) slightly older version of 2015 Community Visual Studio
with similarly older C++ and .Net.
I am running the default flags for the IDE and associated compiling except for the project location.
I have taken your code, dropping the CString, adding a strlen for each match element, and making it a "main" program.

```
#include <regex>   
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    char *pTarget = "-s=35\0";
    std::regex rx("^-(.)=((\\d{1,3})(F|f))*((\\d{1,2})(I|i))*((\\d{1,2})(/(2|4|8|16|32|64))*)*$");
    std::cmatch cm;
    std::regex_match(pTarget, cm, rx);
    if (cm.size() == 0)
    {
        printf("No Matches Found\n");
        return;
    }
    int len;
    for (unsigned idxMatch = 0; idxMatch < cm.size(); idxMatch++)
    {
        len = strlen(cm[idxMatch].str().c_str());
        printf("Found Match %2d ln %d '%s'\n", idxMatch, len, cm[idxMatch].str().c_str());
    }
}
```

It gets the same result that I previously reported.

```
Found Match  0 ln 5 '-s=35'
Found Match  1 ln 1 's'
Found Match  2 ln 0 ''
Found Match  3 ln 0 ''
Found Match  4 ln 0 ''
Found Match  5 ln 0 ''
Found Match  6 ln 0 ''
Found Match  7 ln 0 ''
Found Match  8 ln 1 '5'
Found Match  9 ln 1 '5'
Found Match 10 ln 0 ''
Found Match 11 ln 0 ''
```

Sadly, not the results you are getting.
To me seems to not be a coding issue.
What is you opinion?

Comment: I made a default C++ console project and used the exact code in your post here. It still gives me the correct answer. I've appended the project settings, code and output to my answer. I don't know what to tell you. You might want to get the latest _Update 3_ of Community 2015 and see if that doesn't help.

Comment: @ sln -  Thanks for your efforts. I will take that path.  Unfortunately, I have been delayed on the download because to a tornado 10 miles south here in Dallas area. Oh well, it should be installed by tomorrow.

Comment: @ sln et. al. - First let me thank all of you that responded. I upgraded to the latest Visual Studio (Community 2017) and the code now works.  I made no other changes. Though it is a happy resolution, I find it disturbing that they was an implicit problem with the underlying generated code or with the run time library.

Answer (score 0):

`I am using Microsoft C++ in Visual Studio Community 2015`

I tested your code using the same IDE.
With your code using local variables.

The result is not what you report.
The result I get is correct.

***IDE***

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA378
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
```

***Code***

```
#include <regex>   

char *pTarget = "-s=35\0";
std::regex rx("^-(.)=((\\d{1,3})(F|f))*((\\d{1,2})(I|i))*((\\d{1,2})(/(2|4|8|16|32|64))*)*$");
std::cmatch cm;

CString result = _T("");

std::regex_match( pTarget, cm, rx);

if (cm.size() == 0)
{
    result = "No Matches Found\n";
}
else
{
    for (unsigned idxMatch = 0; idxMatch < cm.size(); idxMatch++)
    {
        char buff[2048] = {'\0'};
        sprintf( buff, "Found Match %d '%s'\n", idxMatch, cm[idxMatch].str().c_str());
        result += buff;
    }
}
this->MessageBox( result, _T(""), MB_ICONINFORMATION );
```

***Output***

[image]

---

Here is a default C++ console project I created to test the code in your *answer*.

The results are still the same. And aren't the ones you've gotten.

Compiler cmdline

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl 
/Fd"x64\Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D 
"NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" 
/errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD 
/Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" 
/Fp"x64\Release\CPP_RxTest1.pch"
```

Linker cmdline

```
/OUT:"C:\Temp\Junk\CPP_RxTest1\x64\Release\CPP_RxTest1.exe" 
/MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT 
/PDB:"C:\Temp\Junk\CPP_RxTest1\x64\Release\CPP_RxTest1.pdb" 
/DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" 
"winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" 
"ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" 
"odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO 
/PGD:"C:\Temp\Junk\CPP_RxTest1\x64\Release\CPP_RxTest1.pgd" 
/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' 
uiAccess='false'" 
/ManifestFile:"x64\Release\CPP_RxTest1.exe.intermediate.mani
fest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

CPP

```
// CPP_RxTest1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <regex>   
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char *pTarget = "-s=35\0";
    std::regex rx("^-(.)=((\\d{1,3})(F|f))*((\\d{1,2})(I|i))*((\\d{1,2})(/(2|4|8|16|32|64))*)*$");
    std::cmatch cm;
    std::regex_match(pTarget, cm, rx);
    if (cm.size() == 0)
    {
        printf("No Matches Found\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int len;
    for (unsigned idxMatch = 0; idxMatch < cm.size(); idxMatch++)
    {
        len = strlen(cm[idxMatch].str().c_str());
        printf("Found Match %2d ln %d '%s'\n", idxMatch, len, cm[idxMatch].str().c_str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Found Match  0 ln 5 '-s=35'
Found Match  1 ln 1 's'
Found Match  2 ln 0 ''
Found Match  3 ln 0 ''
Found Match  4 ln 0 ''
Found Match  5 ln 0 ''
Found Match  6 ln 0 ''
Found Match  7 ln 0 ''
Found Match  8 ln 2 '35'
Found Match  9 ln 2 '35'
Found Match 10 ln 0 ''
Found Match 11 ln 0 ''
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: @ sln - none set